# Java enum method to Delphi

Tags: java, delphi

```
public enum HTTPHeaderKey {
    CACHE_CONTROL("Cache-Control"), CONNECTION("Connection"), TRANSFER_ENCODING("Transfer-Encoding"), HOST("Host"), USER_AGENT("User-Agent"), CONTENT_LENGTH("Content-Length"), CONTENT_TYPE("Content-Type");
    private final String str;

    private HTTPHeaderKey(final String _str) {
        str = _str;
    }

    /** Over ridden toString returns the HTTP/1.1 compatible header */
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
};
```

I am trying to convert this enum to Delphi. I know that how to define enum variables but i have no idea, how can i insert a method in enum?

Or can someone suggest another way to convert this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get part way there with a record helper, which is available for value types from XE3 onwards. For instance:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo;

type
  TMyEnum = (enumValue1, enumValue2);

  TMyEnumHelper = record helper for TMyEnum
  public
    function ToString: string;
  end;

function TMyEnumHelper.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TMyEnum), ord(Self));
end;

begin
  Writeln(enumValue1.ToString);
  Writeln(enumValue2.ToString);
end.
```

This program outputs the following:

```
enumValue1
enumValue2
```

Of course you may prefer to do it like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo;

type
  TMyEnum = (enumValue1, enumValue2);

  TMyEnumHelper = record helper for TMyEnum
  private
    const
      EnumNames: array [TMyEnum] of string = ('Friendly name 1', 'Friendly name 2');
  public
    function ToString: string;
  end;

function TMyEnumHelper.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := EnumNames[Self];
end;

begin
  Writeln(enumValue1.ToString);
  Writeln(enumValue2.ToString);
end.
```

The output here is:

```
Friendly name 1
Friendly name 2
```

This would presumably allow you to tackle the fact the Delphi enumerated types don't support the textual naming that is available in Java.

The other method, the constructor `HTTPHeaderKey` cannot be supported with an enumerated type. The reason being that it requires state, and the only state for a Delphi enumerated type is the enumerated type value itself. You cannot graft on an extra instance variable as is done in the Java code.

All things considered, I don't think an attempt at a literal translation with an enumerated type will work out. I suggest that you translate using either a record or a class, and build the equivalent functionality using the available Delphi language constructs.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that you can use record helpers on enums +1

Comment: @markus_ja 20 minutes ago I didn't know that either

Comment: @David _"20 minutes ago I didn't know that either"_ One of the main benefits I get out out of SO is questions triggering me to try out different things and learn through experimentation. Often question just provide a different angle of looking at something, and it's enough to trigger new ideas.

Comment: This reminds me of a class I wrote some time ago. I wanted to store a value for each value in an enum. And i wanted to be able to load and save it to a string. http://pastebin.com/ntX19RwM

Comment: `The other method, the constructor HTTPHeaderKey cannot be supported with an enumerated type`: the friendly name array could be used to store the HTTP header key

Comment: @mjn that's a value that is associated with the enum instance that is dynamic and known only at runtime. So a structured type (record or class) is needed in Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried to illustrate in my answer below how I would use the friendly names array

Comment: @mjn The code in the question has extra state, `str`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the str field is only used to store the friendly names, only used for the initial construction of the distinct (and immutable) enum values (creation of additional enum values at run time is not possible)

Comment: @mjn I guess I don't understand this properly. I'll check over the weekend and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Davids answer, this modified version should be able to print the HTTP header names:

```
type
  THTTPHeaderKey = (hkCACHE_CONTROL, hkCONNECTION, hkTRANSFER_ENCODING);

  TTHTTPHeaderKeyHelper = record helper for THTTPHeaderKey
  private
    const
      EnumNames: array [THTTPHeaderKey] of string = ('Cache-Control', 'Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
  public
    function ToString: string;
  end;

  // ToString returns the HTTP/1.1 compatible header
  function TTHTTPHeaderKeyHelper.ToString: string;
  begin
    Result := EnumNames[Self];
  end;

  ...
  begin
    Writeln(hkCACHE_CONTROL.ToString);
    Writeln(hkTRANSFER_ENCODING.ToString);
  end.
```

should output

```
Cache-Control
Transfer-Encoding
```