# Creating an enum in DELPHI

Tags: java, delphi, enums

I have an enum codes in JAVA. I convert all JAVA code to DELPHI.

I almost done, but i stucked in here. I have no idea, how to convert enum to Delphi.

I am wondering, this code can be convert to Delphi ?

```
   /**
     * Enum describing the databin class ID's. Methods exist for getting the
     * KakaduClassID and the StandardClassID. I have also included the string
     * representations of the databins as defined for cache model updates.
     * 
     * 
     */
    public enum JPIPDatabinClass {

        /** Precinct data bin class. */
        PRECINCT_DATABIN(KakaduConstants.KDU_PRECINCT_DATABIN, JPIPConstants.PRECINCT_DATA_BIN_CLASS, "P"),

        /** Tile Header data bin class. */
        TILE_HEADER_DATABIN(KakaduConstants.KDU_TILE_HEADER_DATABIN, JPIPConstants.TILE_HEADER_DATA_BIN_CLASS, "H"),

        /** Tile data bin class. */
        TILE_DATABIN(KakaduConstants.KDU_TILE_DATABIN, JPIPConstants.TILE_DATA_BIN_CLASS, "T"),

        /** Main Header data bin class. */
        MAIN_HEADER_DATABIN(KakaduConstants.KDU_MAIN_HEADER_DATABIN, JPIPConstants.MAIN_HEADER_DATA_BIN_CLASS, "Hm"),

        /** Meta data bin class. */
        META_DATABIN(KakaduConstants.KDU_META_DATABIN, JPIPConstants.META_DATA_BIN_CLASS, "M");

        /** The classID as an integer as per the Kakadu library. */
        private int kakaduClassID;

        /** The classID as an integer as per the JPEG2000 Part-9 standard. */
        private int standardClassID;

        /**
         * The classID as a string as per the JPEG2000 Part-9 standard. Used for
         * cache model updates.
         */
        private String jpipString;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * 
         * @param _kakaduClassID
         * @param _standardClassID
         * @param _jpipString
         */
        JPIPDatabinClass(int _kakaduClassID, int _standardClassID, String _jpipString) {
            kakaduClassID = _kakaduClassID;
            standardClassID = _standardClassID;
            jpipString = _jpipString;
        }

        /** Returns the classID as an integer as per the Kakadu library. */
        public int getKakaduClassID() {
            return kakaduClassID;
        }

        /** Returns the classID as an integer as per the JPEG2000 Part-9 standard. */
        public int getStandardClassID() {
            return standardClassID;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the classID as a string as per the JPEG2000 Part-9 standard. Used
         * for cache model updates.
         */
        public String getJpipString() {
            return jpipString;
        }

    };
```

Comment: How you port this part of the code to Delphi probably depends on how you port the code that uses it.  There is no simple one-to-one mapping between Java enums and the available Delphi language facilities. So I personally don't feel equipped to advise you because I don't know your design motivations.

Comment: David is right.  Java enums are a very complicated thing, based on classes.  Delphi enums are much closer to C enums, except that they're typesafe and support the incredibly useful [Pascal sets](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphi_set_type.htm).

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407072/java-enum-method-to-delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Enum can easily be translated to a plain old Delphi class which has a three-argument constructur like the Java Enum, and three read-only public properties.

```
JPIPDatabinClass = class(TObject)
private
  ...
public
  constructor Create(AKakaduClassID: Integer; AStandardClassID: Integer; AJPIP: string);

  property KakaduClassID: Integer; read FKakaduClassID;
  property StandardClassID: Integer; read FStandardClassID;
  property JPIP: string; read FJPIP;
end;
```

and 'singleton style' instances:

```
function PRECINCT_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
function TILE_HEADER_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
...

implementation

var
  FPRECINCT_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
  FTILE_HEADER_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
...
  FPRECINCT_DATABIN := JPIPDatabinClass.Create( ... );
  FTILE_HEADER_DATABIN := JPIPDatabinClass.Create( ... );
...  

function PRECINCT_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
begin
  Result := FPRECINCT_DATABIN;
end;

function TILE_HEADER_DATABIN: JPIPDatabinClass;
begin
  Result := FTILE_HEADER_DATABIN;
end;
...
```

Note: the disadvantage of this approach is that does not create real Delphi enum types, it only emulates the Java enum type as immutable Delphi objects.